# perturbation of exponentiolly stable system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

consider the following system on $\Bbb{R}^n$

> $\dot{x} = f(x,t)+g(x,t) $$  $$ $$ $ $ (*)  $

assume that f(0,t)=g(0,t) = 0 and
1.  0 is an exponentiolly stable equilibrium of $\dot{x}=f(x,t)$
2.$|g(x,t)| \leq \mu|x| $ $\forall x \in \Bbb{R}^n$
show that 0 is is an exponentiolly stable equilibrium of $(*)$
for small enough $\mu$

all I know for now is that x=0 is critical point of g(x,t), so if I define $F(x,t) = f(x,t) +g(x,t)$ and I prove that $DF_0 (=Df_0 + Dg_0 )$ have only negative eigenvalues, then 0 is exponentiolly stable of the system but how can I show that for small enough $\mu$ .

thanks ahead

Comment: Eigenvalues don't play a role here. Do you assume uniform exponential stability or not?

Comment: just exponential stability

Comment: Then I believe that there are counterexamples to the claim, going back to Perron. I won't make it an answer because I was unable to find the reference right now.

Comment: @Jonas What is the definition of *uniform* exponential stability? As far as I know exponential stability is just a special case of uniform asymptotic stability, and the question is true as stated. All the details can be found in Khalil Nonlinear Analysis or [here](http://carmenere.ucsd.edu/jorge/teaching/mae281a/s13/notes/lec06-perturbed.pdf)

Comment: @Artem Never heard of this Khalil. But if you seem to think that it is true, how come you don't know the definition that it involves?

Comment: @Jonas I know the definition of exponential stability. Your original question to OP supposes that you know about *uniform* exponential stability, which is different from "ordinary" one, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Artem Just checked the reference http://carmenere.ucsd.edu/jorge/teaching/mae281a/s13/notes/lec04-non-autonomous.pdf that you gave. The notion is that of uniform exponential stability (the link gives it under the name "exponential stability" in Definition 1.4, but the OP said that the question did not assume uniform exponential stability).

Comment: As I said: if the OP does not assume "uniform exponential stability" (that some people unfortunately call "exponential stability"), the examples of Perron show that the claim is false. Otherwise, if uniform, I agree that it is a very simple exercise that the claim is true.

Comment: @Jonas These notes are somewhat freely copied from the textbook I referenced, which gives exactly the same definition of exponential stability as in the notes. It is quite probable, though it should be asked from OP, that they use exactly the same definition, since this is quite popular book at many engineering and applied math courses dealing with optimal control.

Comment: @Jonas with your definition of stability(uniform exponential stability), how would you prove it?

Comment: From the comments above we agreed that it is the same as in the notes indicated by Artem. So you can look there.